# Could you help me to use font such as Times New Roman, Tahoma with an arbitrary size

Tags: image, text, opencv, drawing, font-size

Could  you tell me to use font such as Times New Roman, Tahoma with an arbitrary size such as 10, 11, 15 and so on. I am going to draw to image a string and show it in a window. I am using openCV

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and what language you are using :)

Comment: Opencv has a small selection of built in fonts only. To use other kinds of fonts you need to do a workaround.

Comment: I am using cvInitFont and see that *only a subset of Hershey fonts are supported. But I dont know how to determine exactly font name while drawing a text to an image

Comment: The supported font names are listed [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html?highlight=cvinitfont#cvInitFont)

Comment: Did you compile opencv with Qt support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python using opencv with the built in fonts goes like this:

```
import cv

image = cv.CreateImage((200,200), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, shear=0, thickness=2, lineType=8)
cv.PutText(image, 'text', (65,100), font, (255,255,255))
cv.ShowImage("image with text", image)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: @Dieu Linh - it should be very easy to adapt the above code :)

Comment: You're supposed to accept to this answer if it answered the question by clicking on the tick next to the answer number.

Comment: Where is it in CV2?